How to use JNI in Quarkus?
I have a native library I want to use in my project. Upon compilation, the library files are located in my project under target/MyLib.dll (Windows) and target/MyLib.so (Linux).
I can use them as wanted in a normal Unit test via System.loadLibrary("MyLib"). However, in a @QuarkusTest, I get this error:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.acme.xxx.new_ObjectInMyLib()'
It seems like I need to enable them differently under Quarkus. I could not find any documentation on that. I found an outdated PR of a quickstart for this, but it does not answer my question. I added the quarkus-core-deployment dependency to my project and found the configuration option quarkus.jni.library-paths, but setting it to quarkus.jni.library-paths=MyLib did not solve the problem.

Why don't use the libs from project Panama ? This is the replacement of JNI.

Because we have used JNI in the past and the native library was developed specifically with JNI in mind. I shall look into Panama nonetheless. A quick google search did not result in Quarkus documentation for it, though. @Serkan, die you have experience with project Panama within Quarkus?

I solved the UnsatisfiedLinkError by moving the part of the code that loads the native library to another repository and include it as a dependency. With that, I was able to use the object that needs the native library in a @QuarkusTest.
